# Location of WindowsApps folder

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, windows-8

How to get location of windows store apps install folder. In my system it is:

> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps

But I have an English Windows 8, so it can be different in other versions. I check [MSDN Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx), but I cannot find this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That location is stored in registry.

I suggest you use this code, instead of second guessing as Max suggests.

```
using (var appx = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Appx"))
{
     var packageRoot = appx.GetValue("PackageRoot");
}
```

Comment: They store a lot of things in registry :) Where else would you store that kind of information?

Answer (score 2):

In general it is the following folder:

> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps

The drive letter C can sometimes be another letter, for example D, but that is rare. Drive C is normally used for system files and application files. If you have a localized Windows (for example a German Windows) the Program Files folder name may have been replaced with another folder name in your language (Programme as it is for german systems).

The folder can also be expressed using an environment variable. The path is then:

> %ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps

But there is no Environment.SpecialFolder entry so far you can use for this.

Comment: Please include proper attribution when copying text from elsewhere.  Your answer is nearly verbatim from http://www.samlogic.net/articles/windows-8-windowsapps-folder.htm